# forming a new list of every nth element from another list, scheme

Tags: list, scheme

quick question that might be obvious.

How would I form a new list of every *n*th element from another list?

For example, say I have this list:

```
(define alphabet '(#\A #\B #\C #\D #\E #\F #\G #\H #\I #\J #\K #\L #\M #\N #\O #\P #\Q #\R #\S #\T #\U #\V #\W #\X #\Y #\Z))
```

How would I form a new list of say, every 2nd element in `alphabet`?

I want to use `list-ref`, but I'm unsure how to iterate through the list correctly.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
(define (build-list alphabet output-list count temp-count limit)
  (cond
  ((= temp-count limit) output-list)
  (else (define new-list (append output-list (list-ref alphabet count))) (build-list alphabet output-list (+ count 2) (+ temp-count 1) limit))))
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Using `list-ref` is not a good idea, you'll end up traversing the list more than strictly necessary, it's better if we use the indexes to our advantage. Try this:

```
(define (build-list alphabet count limit)
  (cond ((null? alphabet) '())
        ((= count limit)
         (cons (car alphabet)
               (build-list (cdr alphabet) 1 limit)))
        (else
         (build-list (cdr alphabet) (+ count 1) limit))))
```

For example, to take one element every second element including the first element do this:

```
(build-list alphabet 2 2) ; set count and limit to the same value
=> '(#\A #\C #\E #\G #\I #\K #\M #\O #\Q #\S #\U #\W #\Y)
```

To skip the first element and starting from there take every second element:

```
(build-list alphabet 1 2) ; set count to 1
=> '(#\B #\D #\F #\H #\J #\L #\N #\P #\R #\T #\V #\X #\Z)
```

To output the whole list:

```
(build-list alphabet 1 1) ; set count to 1 and limit to 1
=> '(#\A #\B #\C #\D #\E #\F #\G #\H #\I #\J #\K #\L #\M
     #\N #\O #\P #\Q #\R #\S #\T #\U #\V #\W #\X #\Y #\Z)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use filter for this? I imagine it like `(filter (= (mod counter++ n) 0)) alphabet)` but that's not real code. Filter seems to need a function that takes the list items, for one thing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler sure, it's possible, by keeping track of the indexes and filtering the ones we need. It's contrived though, and not worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative solution.

To get every, say, fifth element: keep the first element and skip the next four,
then repeat.

```
#lang racket

(define (drop n xs)
  (if (or (= n 0) (empty? xs))
      xs
      (drop (- n 1) (cdr xs))))

(define (every-nth n xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      '()
      (cons (first xs)
            (every-nth n (drop n xs)))))

;; Examples:
> (every-nth 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
'(1 4 7)
> (every-nth 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
'(1 4 7 10)
```